# How to either accept a Object or a List<Object> as a parameter in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there any way to accept an specific `Type` of that object or a `List` of that `Type` as a function/constructor parameter with **type checks**?

This thing can be achieved by the below code. But I want the IDE to explicitly warn the user if the user passes an unexpected type of Object. Maybe something like type annonation...

Code:

```
sampleFunction(Object o)
{
  if(o is Type){
    // do something with o
  } else (o is List<Type>){
    // use for-each loop and ...
  } else {
    throw [...];
  }
}
```

Comment: Nope.  If you want static type-checking, you will need separate functions for each type.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to get you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: There is no way to have a single function that takes multiple types *and* can be statically type checked (i.e., checked during build time instead of at runtime).  You instead should have one function that operates on a single element and a separate function that operates on a `List` (or `Iterable`).

Comment: Can something be done with https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options?

Comment: I don't think you should try create custom analysis options as a work around for the type system. Instead, just create two methods: `sampleFunction(Object)` and `sampleFunctionFromList(List<Object>)`

Comment: Could this solve my issue? Not sure from Validator came though ... https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/4596#issuecomment-108327746

Answer (score 3):

No.

The Dart type system does not have any way to express general union types (one type *or* another unrelated type). There are two built-in union types in the type system: `FutureOr` and nullable types (which become explicit with the Null Safety language update that is currently in development). No other union types can be expression, so you can't specify "either `Foo` or `List<Foo>`" as a type in any way.

The only solution is to pick a type which is a supertype of *both*, usually `dynamic`, and then check inside the function whether it's a `Foo`, a `List<Foo>`, or something else - which is then an error.

Comment: Is there any way to condition the IDE to warn about something?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using **optional named parameters** available in dart.
For example:

```
void cumstomParameters({List<Object> objects, Object singleObject}){
  print(objects);
  print(singleObject);
}
```

This takes two parameters which can be of the `type` you need, user can pass anyone of the `types` using the `name`
Like:

```
void main() {
cumstomParameters(objects: ['This','is','list','of','Strings']);
cumstomParameters(singleObject: 'This is Only one String');
}
```

Output:

```
[This, is, list, of, Strings]
null
null
This is Only one String
```

**Null aware operators** will be needed inside `cumstomParameters(...)` to handle which parameter was passed, but this way `type` restriction can be managed.

Sorry, my previous answer about using linter rules was incorrect. Custom linter rules are not yet avaiable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to warn the user that a value can only be passed either to `objects` or `singleObject` and not both?

Comment: No, optional named parameters don't have that feature. But you can mark any of the parameters as required with @required annotation https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters to enforce users to provide a value.

Comment: Your other comment mentioned you are trying this for constructors. I would suggest using two named constructors. I think that is one of the simpler ways to achieve the feature needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this workaround :

```dart
void sampleFunction(List<Object> objects) {
    if (objects.length == 1)
        // do something with objects[0]
    else if (objects.length > 1) 
        // use for-each loop and ...
    else 
        // Empty list
}
```

To use :

```dart
final i = 12;
final list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
sampleFunction([i]);
sampleFunction(list);
```

Comment: I know that's possible but I wanted it to be possible without that....Btw, I am trying to implement that sort of type-check for an constructor.